# How to choose certain nodes/words from a string

Tags: string, xquery

I have this code

```
for $sea in distinct-values (doc("mondial.xml")//island/tokenize(@sea,"\s"))
let $count := count(doc("mondial.xml")//island[@sea = $sea]/tokenize(@sea,"\s"))
let $seacount := concat($sea," ",$count)
return $seacount
```

Which returns to me

"sea-ArcticOcean 3 sea-Greenlandsea 0 sea-NorwegianSea 1 sea-BarentsSea 0

sea-Atlantic 53 sea-LabradorSea 0 ..." and so on.

The number Is as you can see $count and the sea-XXX part Is the variable $sea. What I'm stuck on now Is somehow choosing the $sea which has the max value of $count of all of the counts and displaying that sea-name. I've tried things like adding a $max variable to:

```
 for $sea in distinct-values (doc("mondial.xml")//island/tokenize(@sea,"\s"))
let $count := count(doc("mondial.xml")//island[@sea = $sea]/tokenize(@sea,"\s"))
let $seacount := concat($sea," ",$count)
$max := concat($sea," ",max($count))
return $max
```

Also tried adding an order by $count (descending) statement and then returning the first node:

```
for $sea in distinct-values (doc("mondial.xml")//island/tokenize(@sea,"\s"))
let $count := count(doc("mondial.xml")//island[@sea = $sea]/tokenize(@sea,"\s"))
let $seacount := concat($sea," ",$count)
order by $count descending
return $seacount[1]
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way or ?

Comment: Please also reference the input you're using, and provide actual and expected output of the queries you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will return the first node of the result sequence **for each** iteration. In this case, `$seacount` is always a squence of 1 string, so you are always selecting the equivalent of `('sea-value count')[1]`, which is simply the singleton string value. To select only one overall, wrap the whole query in parens to create a sequence of all the values for all iterations, and then select the first of those:

```
(for $sea in distinct-values (doc("mondial.xml")//island/tokenize(@sea,"\s"))
let $count := count(doc("mondial.xml")//island[@sea = $sea]/tokenize(@sea,"\s"))
let $seacount := concat($sea," ",$count)
order by $count descending
return $seacount)[1]
```